# Sendmail Header Rewrite (incoming mail, BCC/undisclosed-recipients to TO) (Centos)

Tags: header, centos, url-rewriting, sendmail, bcc

my server uses sendmail 8.13.8 for incoming and outgoing.

I get spam destined to undisclosed-recipients -  (see below example) i wish to know which address the spammer sent this to as my mailbox uses catch all from several domains...

I aware  i can go to a maillog but that file can be very big . Is there way to rewrite Sendmail header name to always show TO instead of always getting undisclosed-recipients or the BCC address the spammer entered? such as his own? i spent a few months searching for results so i thought i would ask, thank you in advance.

```
From: Micheal Manka [mailto:micheal.manka103@gmail.com] 
Sent: Monday, February 03, 2014 11:15 PM
To: undisclosed-recipients:
Subject: Order

Dear Sir/Madam
I would like to purchase Trap Doors r from your shop.What types of them you have 
in the size and what would be the prices? What types of payments do you accept? 
Looking forward to hear from you soon.

Regards,

Micheal Manka
```

Comment: How have you configured the catch all? [There are a few ways]  Which email client do you use to read catch all mailbox?

Comment: hi, i used the mapping file /etc/mail/virtusertable    @mydomain.com Address me . 
I use outlook 2010.

Comment: If you use procmail as you local mailer (typical on linuxes) and accept one copy per every recipient then it is trivial. Do you want trivial or complex solution?

Comment: hi, im not sure, i tried to switch from sendmail to procmail seem very complicated and was not a smooth transition so i went back..

Comment: Sendmail may use procmail as a helper program (mailer).  Sendmail is an SMTP server, procmail is not.

Comment: i understand that, but getting procmail to use the aliases/virtuser was a nightmare - any suggestions for a smooth transition?

Answer (score 0):

[Sendmail FAQ 3.29 : How can I add a header specifying the actual recipient when having multiple users in a virtual domain go to a single mailbox?](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/faq_ver_8_issues/#3.29)

The simple version with one copy per every recipient passes username as $1 to ~catchall/.procmailrc

virtusertable:

```
@mydomain.com  catchall+%1
```

The more complicate version http://anfi.homeunix.org/sendmail/sharedmailbox.html mentioned at the end of the FAQ entry is available at http://www.jmaimon.com/sendmail/anfi.homeunix.net/sendmail/sharedmailbox.html